# How to test "swipe" event in android application on different devices (other than emulators)?

Tags: android, gesture

I have used Android SDK for testing an application. But the emulator is quite slow and the "swipe" event does not get triggered instantly as in physical devices. Also there is a limited number of devices available on Android SDK for testing. Is there any other way for testing Android gesture efficiently and having a wide range of devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to you genymotion A faster Android emulator

https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/

Comment: Using the genymotion emulator, how do you make a swipe gesture?  Is there a special keyboard mouse combination?  I've tried several combinations to no avail.